# Can you use openshift to deploy non-web applications?

Tags: openshift

I cannot seem to find a direct and recent answer to this question.  It appears to me that OpenShift is used only to deploy web-application (by the languages supported, etc.) but I want to make sure.  Can you only use OpenShift to deploy web applications?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information at:

- https://www.openshift.com/

On that page it says:

> Run multiple languages, frameworks, and databases on the same platform and take advantage of the docker eco-system.

That statement links to:

- https://www.openshift.com/features/technologies.html

where it lists various language builders provided as well as images for database products.

If you can package something up in a container image, then generally you can run it. The caveat is that OpenShift by default doesn't allow you to run containers as root and will assign you a uid for it to be run as. Many images on Docker Hub use poor practices and expect to be run as root. These will not usually work out of the box. On an OpenShift system which you have no admin rights, and especially a multi user system, you will not be able to, nor would you be given the ability to run stuff as root, so you just need to follow good practices on how your image is setup if building your own images from scratch.